# Error to build or debug Appcelerator 4.8.1.201612050850

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

To find the cause, I first set the notification level from "info" to "debug" and now this shows up in the console when compiling the app:`2017-01-14T08:25:42.969Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot read property 'executables' of null
2017-01-14T08:25:42.970Z | ERROR  | Cannot read property 'executables' of null
2017-01-14T08:25:42.970Z | TRACE  | TypeError: Cannot read property 'executables' of null
    at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/simulator.js:174:49
    at fireCallbacks (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/xcode.js:105:5)
    at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/xcode.js:502:11
    at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3694:9
    at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:356:16
    at replenish (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:877:25)
    at iterateeCallback (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:867:17)
    at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:840:16
    at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3691:13
    at apply (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:21:25)
    at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:56:12
    at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:356:16
    at eachOfArrayLike (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:929:9)
    at eachOf (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:991:5)
    at Object.eachLimit (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3089:3)

### at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/xcode.js:415:12

```
at Object.run (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:59:8)
at find (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:96:14)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:987:13
at Immediate.q.process (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:953:21)
```

### at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:396:17)

```
at Object.setImmediate (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:194:9)
at _insert (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:890:19)
at Object.q.push (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:927:17)
at Object.findExecutable (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:113:8)
at findTeams (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/xcode.js:405:21)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3686:9
at replenish (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:882:17)
at iterateeCallback (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:867:17)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:840:16
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3691:13
at apply (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:21:25)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:56:12
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:356:16
at replenish (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:877:25)
```

### at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:886:9

```
at Object.run (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:59:8)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/xcode.js:222:22
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/env.js:98:4
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3694:9
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:356:16
at iterateeCallback (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:865:24)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:840:16
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3691:13
at apply (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:21:25)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:56:12
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/env.js:76:6
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:100:8
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:60:3)
```

### at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)

```
at Object.run (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:59:8)
at find (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:96:14)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:987:13
at Immediate.q.process (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:953:21)
```

### at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:396:17)

```
at Object.setImmediate (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:194:9)
at _insert (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:890:19)
at Object.q.push (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/node-appc/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:927:17)
at Object.findExecutable (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:113:8)
at async.parallel.security (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/env.js:64:21)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3686:9
at replenish (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:882:17)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:886:9
at eachOfLimit (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:913:22)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:918:16
at eachOf (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:991:5)
at _parallel (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3685:5)
at Object.parallelLimit [as parallel] (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3765:3)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/env.js:62:9
```

### at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/utilities.js:66:17

```
at magik (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/utilities.js:51:13)
at Object.detect (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/env.js:49:9)
at detectOSXenv (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/xcode.js:207:9)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3686:9
at replenish (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:882:17)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:886:9
at eachOfLimit (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:913:22)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:918:16
at _parallel (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3685:5)
at Object.series (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:4525:3)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/xcode.js:204:9
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/utilities.js:66:17
at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:436:9)
```

### at process._tickCallback (node.js:365:13)

```
at magik (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/utilities.js:51:13)
at Object.detect (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/xcode.js:98:27)
at detectXcode (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/index.js:114:11)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3686:9
at eachOfArrayLike (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:941:9)
at eachOf (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:991:5)
at _parallel (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3685:5)
at Object.parallelLimit [as parallel] (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3765:3)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/index.js:76:9
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/utilities.js:66:17
at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:436:9)
```

### at process._tickCallback (node.js:365:13)

```
at magik (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/lib/utilities.js:51:13)
at Object.detect (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/ioslib/index.js:46:9)
at iOSBuilder.<anonymous> (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/iphone/cli/commands/_build.js:329:10)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/titanium-sdk/lib/titanium.js:99:5
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3671:13
at eachOfArrayLike (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1002:13)
at eachOf (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1052:9)
at _parallel (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3670:9)
at Object.parallelLimit [as parallel] (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3750:7)
at Object.exports.platformOptions (/Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/node_modules/titanium-sdk/lib/titanium.js:76:8)
at /Users/kings/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.2.v20161221155621/cli/commands/build.js:49:7
at /Users/kings/.appcelerator/install/6.1.0/package/node_modules/titanium/lib/hook.js:256:13
at /Users/kings/.appcelerator/install/6.1.0/package/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3853:9
at /Users/kings/.appcelerator/install/6.1.0/package/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:484:16
at replenish (/Users/kings/.appcelerator/install/6.1.0/package/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1025:25)
```

`

Comment: I do it but always the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this! (For me at least)

All I did was to remove (archived) the workspace (E.g in ~/Document/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace

I think the issue was tied to some sort of  cache form the workspace. Since I removed it, I can easily build in all simulators and devices.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you changed Xcode location. Try to set right location with command:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /path_to/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: I do it but always the same problem

Comment: Show me result of command:

   `sudo xcode-select -p`

It must be something like:

.../Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Answer (score 0):

Xcode was missing that caused me the error. Although I only made the build for Android, which is a bit strange.

Comment: this looks like a guess answer to a badly formulated question which is not worth existence